# understand process memory map in linux

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, x86-64, glibc

I am trying to understand the basic of linux process memory layout and i got this program:

```
#include <stdio.h> // standard io
#include <stdlib.h> // C standard library
#include <pthread.h> // threading
#include <unistd.h> // unix standard library
#include <sys/types.h> // system types for linux

// getchar basically is like "read"
// it prompts the user for input
// in this case, the input is thrown away
// which makes similar to a "pause" continuation primitive 
// but a pause that is resolved through user input, which we promptly throw away!
void * thread_func (void * arg) {

    printf("Before malloc in thread 1\n");
    getchar();
    char * addr = (char *) malloc(1000);
    printf("After malloc and before free in thread 1\n");
    getchar();
    free(addr);
    printf("After free in thread 1\n");
    getchar();

}

int main () {

    char * addr;
    printf("Welcome to per thread arena example::%d\n", getpid());
    printf("Before malloc in the main thread\n");
    getchar();
    addr = (char *) malloc(1000);
    printf("After malloc and before free in main thread\n");
    getchar();
    free(addr);
    printf("After free in main thread\n");
    getchar();

    // pointer to the thread 1
    pthread_t thread_1;
    // pthread_* functions return 0 upon succeeding, and other numbers upon failing
    int pthread_status;

    pthread_status = pthread_create(&thread_1, NULL, thread_func, NULL);

    if (pthread_status != 0) {
        printf("Thread creation error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // returned status code from thread_1
    void * thread_1_status;

    pthread_status = pthread_join(thread_1, &thread_1_status);

    if (pthread_status != 0) {
        printf("Thread join error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I started the program, the content in `/proc/<pid>/maps` is:

```
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1323314                            /home/oscp/xg/c/memory_layout/a.out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:01 1323314                            /home/oscp/xg/c/memory_layout/a.out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 1323314                            /home/oscp/xg/c/memory_layout/a.out
7fcc372d7000-7fcc37491000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1053757                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7fcc37491000-7fcc37691000 ---p 001ba000 08:01 1053757                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7fcc37691000-7fcc37695000 r--p 001ba000 08:01 1053757                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7fcc37695000-7fcc37697000 rw-p 001be000 08:01 1053757                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7fcc37697000-7fcc3769c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc3769c000-7fcc376b5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1053877                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
7fcc376b5000-7fcc378b4000 ---p 00019000 08:01 1053877                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
7fcc378b4000-7fcc378b5000 r--p 00018000 08:01 1053877                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
7fcc378b5000-7fcc378b6000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 1053877                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
7fcc378b6000-7fcc378ba000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc378ba000-7fcc378dd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1053733                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7fcc37abe000-7fcc37ac1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc37ad8000-7fcc37adc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc37adc000-7fcc37add000 r--p 00022000 08:01 1053733                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7fcc37add000-7fcc37ade000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 1053733                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7fcc37ade000-7fcc37adf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffdc1cff000-7ffdc1d20000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffdc1dd8000-7ffdc1ddb000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffdc1ddb000-7ffdc1ddd000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

What are the purposes of these memory regions?

```
7fcc37491000-7fcc37691000 ---p 001ba000 08:01 1053757                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
...
7fcc37abe000-7fcc37ac1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc37ad8000-7fcc37adc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

---

Then I press enter a few times after running the program. After it prints "Before malloc in thread 1". The memory layout looks like below:

```
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1323314                            /home/oscp/xg/c/memory_layout/a.out
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:01 1323314                            /home/oscp/xg/c/memory_layout/a.out
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:01 1323314                            /home/oscp/xg/c/memory_layout/a.out
00632000-00653000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fcc36ad6000-7fcc36ad7000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc36ad7000-7fcc372d7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc372d7000-7fcc37491000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1053757                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7fcc37491000-7fcc37691000 ---p 001ba000 08:01 1053757                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7fcc37691000-7fcc37695000 r--p 001ba000 08:01 1053757                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7fcc37695000-7fcc37697000 rw-p 001be000 08:01 1053757                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7fcc37697000-7fcc3769c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc3769c000-7fcc376b5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1053877                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
7fcc376b5000-7fcc378b4000 ---p 00019000 08:01 1053877                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
7fcc378b4000-7fcc378b5000 r--p 00018000 08:01 1053877                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
7fcc378b5000-7fcc378b6000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 1053877                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so
7fcc378b6000-7fcc378ba000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc378ba000-7fcc378dd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1053733                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7fcc37abe000-7fcc37ac1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc37ad8000-7fcc37adc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc37adc000-7fcc37add000 r--p 00022000 08:01 1053733                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7fcc37add000-7fcc37ade000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 1053733                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7fcc37ade000-7fcc37adf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffdc1cff000-7ffdc1d20000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffdc1dd8000-7ffdc1ddb000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffdc1ddb000-7ffdc1ddd000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

What are the purposes of these two regions?

```
7fcc36ad6000-7fcc36ad7000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc36ad7000-7fcc372d7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

After it prints "After malloc and before free in thread 1", it creates another two regions below:

```
7fcc30000000-7fcc30021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc30021000-7fcc34000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
```

What are the purposes of these two regions?

Comment: The mappings with no permissions might be some kind of "guard" page, and/or reserving the virtual address space for future growth (to prevent an `mmap(NULL, ...)` from randomly choosing it.

Answer (score 10):

Your question covers many completely different things, so the answer will be long.

**The first question** is the meaning of

```
7fcc37491000-7fcc37691000 ---p 001ba000 08:01 1053757                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
```

in

```
7fcc372d7000-7fcc37491000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1053757                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7fcc37491000-7fcc37691000 ---p 001ba000 08:01 1053757                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7fcc37691000-7fcc37695000 r--p 001ba000 08:01 1053757                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7fcc37695000-7fcc37697000 rw-p 001be000 08:01 1053757                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
```

This inaccessible memory region is a gap between adjacent ELF segments of the library (which is supposed to occupy the contiguous chunk of memory). The `---p` protection mode forbids using this gap for occasional memory allocation. If you `strace(1)` the process when it loads the library, you may see something like this:

```
mmap(NULL, 1848896, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3</usr/lib/libc-2.28.so>, 0) = 0x7f9673d8f000
mprotect(0x7f9673db1000, 1671168, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9673db1000, 1355776, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3</usr/lib/libc-2.28.so>, 0x22000) = 0x7f9673db1000
mmap(0x7f9673efc000, 311296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3</usr/lib/libc-2.28.so>, 0x16d000) = 0x7f9673efc000
mmap(0x7f9673f49000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3</usr/lib/libc-2.28.so>, 0x1b9000) = 0x7f9673f49000
```

The first `mmap()` maps the first ELF segment into the memory but reserves the space for *whole* library. This is done to allow the kernel to choose the location for the library on its discretion. To protect any possible gaps between segments `mprotect(..., PROT_NONE)` is called; then all remaining segments are mapped into the memory using `mmap()` - this also changes the protection mode of the appropriate memory pages from `---p` to whatever mode the segment requires. You may have some fun by taking a look at [how it actually works](https://git.launchpad.net/glibc/tree/elf/dl-load.c?h=release/2.19/master#n1276). If you want to verify how this `---p` gap is formed during the loading, you may also use `readelf(1)` with library's binary and do some hexadecimal math with segments' locations and alignments, collating the results with the output of `strace`.

**The second question** are the following anonymous mappings:

```
7fcc36ad6000-7fcc36ad7000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc36ad7000-7fcc372d7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

This looks like a thread stack for `thread 1`. The second mapping is the stack itself (`372d7000` - `36ad7000` = `800000` = 8 MiB, which is a default stack size limit in many distros, which, in turn, is a default stack size for `pthread`), and the first one is a stack guard page. This page with mode `---p` protects the stack from overflowing, and triggers the segfault when the overflow happens (because of a write to this write-protected page).

Note: in older Linux kernels, the thread stacks were annotated with `[stack:TID]` names in `maps` file, but this feature was removed, so I cannot *guarantee* that this mapping is really a thread stack (though it looks like). However, you may use `strace` to find the exact thread's stack location from `child_stack` argument of `clone()` syscall and compare with this mapping.

Going on. **The third question** is

```
7fcc30000000-7fcc30021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc30021000-7fcc34000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
```

Well, this is what `malloc()` in `thread 1` did to allocate the memory you have requested. In short, the whole region `7fcc30000000-7fcc34000000` is a *heap*, from which allocations are done. The `rw-p` interval `7fcc30000000-7fcc30021000`, allocated from this heap, will grow as you will request more and more memory with `malloc()`. When this heap will deplete, new one will be requested using `mmap()`.

As you probably noticed, I don't have an explanation for the following mappings in your question:

```
7fcc37abe000-7fcc37ac1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fcc37ad8000-7fcc37adc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

I can't recognize those guys quickly and not sure that these are ordinary allocations. Probably this needs separate investigation, as this topic is already too long.

Comment: That might be TLS maybe?

Comment: There are few more small anon mappings pretty similar to these two, so I can't prove the purpose of each particular one of them and say "this one is definitely a TLS". It would be better to check each of them with debugger individually to be sure (`catch syscall mmap` and then see who is caller).

Comment: Regarding the answer to the third question, if you see the malloc in the main thread, you will find the malloc does not generate a protected region. i.e., press "enter" until it prints "After malloc and before free in main thread". Why is that?

Comment: The main thread here uses the region marked with `[heap]`. You may do 1000 `malloc()`s of 100k chunks and you will see this region growing. This region is a bit special for historical reason and resized not by `mmap()` syscall, but by `brk()`. You may be interested in reading some stuff about how glibc's `malloc()` works, e.g. https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals.